# How to fix "Failed to snapshot build script"

Tags: flutter, dart

I installed flutter for web and dart sdk. Added to path bin folders. Ran `flutter pub global activate webdev` and `flutter pub upgrade`, but after entering `webdev serve` I always getting error":

```
[SEVERE] Failed to snapshot build script .dart_tool/build/entrypoint/build.dart.
[SEVERE] This is likely caused by a misconfigured builder definition.
[SEVERE] /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/protobuf-0.13.16/lib/src/protobuf/builder_info.dart:43:34: Error: Method not found: 'MapFieldInfo.map'.    _addField(MapFieldInfo<K, V>.map(name, tagNumber, index, PbFieldType.M,                                 ^^^/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/protobuf-0.13.16/lib/src/protobuf/field_info.dart:45:9: Error: '_mapEntryBuilderInfo' isn't an instance field of this class.        _mapEntryBuilderInfo = null {        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/protobuf-0.13.16/lib/src/protobuf/field_info.dart:61:9: Error: '_mapEntryBuilderInfo' isn't an instance field of this class.        _mapEntryBuilderInfo = null;        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/protobuf-0.13.16/lib/src/protobuf/field_info.dart:68:9: Error: '_mapEntryBuilderInfo' isn't an instance field of this class.        _mapEntryBuilderInfo = null {        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/protobuf-0.13.16/lib/src/protobuf/field_info.dart:82:12: Error: '_mapEntryBuilderInfo' isn't an instance field of this class.      this._mapEntryBuilderInfo])           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/protobuf-0.13.16/lib/src/protobuf/field_info.dart:199:9: Error: Superclass has no constructor named 'FieldInfo._'.      : super._(        ^^^^^/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/protobuf-0.13.16/lib/src/protobuf/field_info.dart:195:21: Error: Final field '_mapEntryBuilderInfo' is not initialized.Try to#7      _CommandRunner.runCommand (package:webdev/src/webdev_command_runner.dart:38:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      CommandRunner.run.<anonymous closure> (package:args/command_runner.dart:112:25)
#9      new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:224:31)
#10     CommandRunner.run (package:args/command_runner.dart:112:14)
#11     run (package:webdev/src/webdev_command_runner.dart:19:56)
#12     main (file:///C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webdev-2.5.1/bin/webdev.dart:17:22)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:303:32)
#14     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)
```

flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.356], locale ru-RU)
[X] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    X Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set ANDROID_HOME to that location.
      You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[√] VS Code (version 1.38.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
name: addd
description: An app built using Flutter for web

environment:
  # You must be using Flutter >=1.5.0 or Dart >=2.3.0
  sdk: '>=2.3.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter_web: any
  flutter_web_ui: any

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.5.0
  build_web_compilers: ^2.1.0
  pedantic: ^1.7.0

dependency_overrides:
  flutter_web:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages/flutter_web
  flutter_web_ui:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages/flutter_web_ui
```

How fix that?

UPD. Added some more detailts (flutter doctor and pubspec.yaml)

Comment: Could you run `flutter doctor` and provide your pubspec.yaml file?

Comment: Try to use protobuf-0.13.15 in dependens

Comment: @Nuts Added, though I dont think that flutter doctor will help.

Comment: could u run `pub run build_runner clean` and maybe `pub cache repair`

Comment: @Nuts didn't fixed

Comment: Have u tried running `flutter clean`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I got the same problem today too. By some luck & comparing to a working build, I found that it is broken by protobuf version > 0.13.15.

The short term fix:

In `pubspec.yaml` under dependencies force downgrade the version of protobuf to be 0.13.15:

```
dependencies:
  protobuf: <=0.13.15
```

Run `pub get` then `webdev serve` as normal.

Comment: The correct fix for stagehand created `web-angular` apps where updating protobuf isn't a straightforward option.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem too but after some research I finded that the problem is that the protobuf version is outdated try using the newest version which is 0.14.1 in `pubspec.yaml`

```
  dependencies:
  protobuf: <=0.14.1
```

you can check the newest version [from here](https://pub.dev/packages/protobuf)

Answer (score 0):

I installed the flutter enviroment yesterday and it works fine. Today I tried to start the project again and get the same error.

flutter doctor

```
 Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
 [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 
 10.0.18362.356], locale en-US)
 [X] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
     X Unable to locate Android SDK.
       Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
       On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
       (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).
       If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set ANDROID_HOME to that location.
       You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable. 

 [!] Android Studio (not installed)
 [!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.2)
     X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
     X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
 [√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.38.0)
 [!] Connected device
     ! No devices available

 ! Doctor found issues in 4 categories.
```

pubspec.yaml

```
 name: demo
 description: An app built using Flutter for web

 environment:
   # You must be using Flutter >=1.5.0 or Dart >=2.3.0
   sdk: '>=2.3.0 <3.0.0'

 dependencies:
   flutter_web: any
   flutter_web_ui: any

 dev_dependencies:
   build_runner: ^1.5.0
   build_web_compilers: ^2.1.0
   pedantic: ^1.7.0

 dependency_overrides:
   flutter_web:
     git:
       url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
       path: packages/flutter_web
   flutter_web_ui:
     git:
       url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
       path: packages/flutter_web_ui
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got into this error. The problem I faced is that I used some packages **old versions** which are not null safety supported. So I upgraded the packages and fixed the error.

In my case I used a lower version of `freezed` package. and upgrading it fixed my issue. Related to Massaget's problem, its `protobuf` package